# Creating a variable price button with the php coinbase api

Tags: php, coinbase-php

I'm using [coinbase-php](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) and have run into a problem:

I have tried so many things but I honestly don't understand how to pass options to the create button function. I noticed how they pass the description option but when I try to do the same for variable_price it does not appear to work. Here is what I tried:

```
$button = $coinbase->createButton("TipModel", "0.01", "USD", "", array("variable_price" => True))->embedHtml;
```

It still is a fixed price though.

Comment: You should mention, which framework you are using as `createButton` is not a PHP core function.

Comment: php coinbase api, see title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the `choose_price` option too, it seems to work. Try this:

```
$button = $coinbase->createButton("TipModel", "0.01", "USD", "", array("variable_price" => true, 'choose_price' => true))->embedHtml;
```

Comment: :( didn't get the 100 karma!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug, your code seems to be correct. Some one else commented it too that the variable_price does not work in the php api.

> Vladimir • a month ago
>
> There is a problem with creating customized
>   button with option "variable_price"=>"true" using coinbase.php class
>   from github. Such a button does not have input field for number of btc
>   to send. The value is fixed, no matters variable_price is set for true
>   or false. All other custom options works good.

https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/buttons/create.html

Comment: Interestingly, after looking at the code I see no reason it should be any different than other options, however, it does appear that there is something wrong with it. Possibly there could even be something wrong with the coinbase api. I am going to start a bounty to see if anyone can come up with a work around.